# Reference: Bethe Ansatz Equations

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, integrable-systems

Could someone show me good references to find solutions of the Bethe Ansatz Equations, for simple cases (using algebraic geometry or others interfaces with mathematics)?

For example in the case of XXZ model (arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0306002), but don't have enough knowledge in this topic, so I found few articles, then any good references are welcome.

Comment: this? https://people.sissa.it/~ffranchi/BAnotes.pdf

Comment: No, my question was vogue. I will rephrase it.

Comment: I added a reference on numerical methods in my answer; both methods are quite pretty from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: Note: Going forward I will edit this subject by putting other references. A friend mine, recently published a paper concerning this: http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.4645v3.pdf) you can find a numerical treatment of the Bethe equations for the isotropic spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ Heisenberg quantum spin chain with periodic boundary conditions.

A conjecture on the number of solutions with pairwise distinct roots of these Bethe equations in terms of numbers of so-called singular (or exceptional) solutions is formulated. More concretely, the  motivation behind the discussion in the reference is the completeness of the Bethe equations solutions and the presence of so called singular / exceptional solutions. These can be physical or unphysical.

In order to check the conjecture proposed in the paper one needs to find all solutions with pairwise distinct roots of the Bethe equations. As the check is highly non trivial, two numerical methods -homotopy continuation and the Baxter T-Q equation- are discussed up to an upper bound in the number of quantum spins in the one dimensional quantum spin chain.

The homotopy continuation method finds the solutions of a polynomial system (in this case the Bethe equations) starting with a second polynomial system  (the start system) and a set of nonsingular solutions of it. The methods deforms the start system and the corresponding solutions to the system under interest to determine the solutions of the latter.

The Baxter T-Q equation method uses the model integrability; all details are contained in section 4 *loc. cit*.

Comment: Thank you Avitus, I had heard about this, but didn't get to see this article, thank you by the your explanation. Nepomechie presented this work in Brazil http://www.iip.ufrn.br/?pg==oFWaxmYuJleYNjQ5JmMklXWXBTP&lang=en&inf===gTUFUP, but was unable to attend. Kirillov and Sakamoto have this recently article, which is already an continuation, did not get to read, but I'll leave here to complement.

Comment: You are welcome. Please feel free to flag / upvote the answer if you found it useful. I also found these notes: http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/introbethe.html I hope they help

Comment: The notes already knew, but I try something with mathematics interface. The article that you Indicated to me has many good references there, including the reference of the Langlands. I've already given one upvote.

Comment: Thanks for upvote. Btw "flagging an answer" refers to accepting an answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work .

Comment: I know, I'll wait a bit (one week) if there will be more answers, to analyze all and not to commit injustice.